# Webpage source not completely read by HTTPClient

Tags: http, inputstream, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader, androidhttpclient

I am able to download smaller JSON responses with the following code just fine:

```html
    public String getHTTPData() {

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(BASE_URL)).openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        } catch (Throwable t) {

            t.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                inputStream.close();

                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            } catch (Throwable t) {

                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

but when I couldn't find a certain API (Chinese dictionary API), I thought I might as well parse the HTML source code for the data I need. But I only seem to get the first 100 lines of the source code. I must be missing something very simple like a 'maxLength' HTTP parameter or a timeout. Didn't find anything in SO, also tried the code suggested by Google [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) and ran into the same issue. I'm not sure how to further debug this, I see that the inputstream dries up and returns '-1' (tried different maxLength chunks in 'readStream' and got smaller blocks but still dried up in the end), so I assume it's the URLConnection not delivering. Or is it maybe my inputstream code that's faulty ? btw, this is an https URL, but since I do get some initial data, I don't think it's a protocol issue (hope I summarized this somewhat intelligently ...)

Comment: any suggestions on how to debug this ?

Comment: OMG, I'm so dumb, finally figured it out. I got the entire page all along, but I used 'Log.i' to look at the response and apparently the logging itself is truncated after 200 chars or so. (finally used a TextView to check it), probably the debugger would have caught that nicely as well, d'oh

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to run your code in a thread and not on the main thread.
Also please add this to your request:

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Then check the response code :

```
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
}
```

Do not forget to add the Internet permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, yes, I had the manifest line and I checked the response (it's 200 i.e. ok). As I said, I do get chunks of data, when I limit it to 100000, I get the following: 100000 + 100000 + 5308 i.e. I get 3 buffers and the remainder. I also get the full page source via curl.